# Cannot push a view controller after successful login

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to send it to another view on successful login so I am just testing my logic at this stage

```
 let viewController:UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myMainView") as! mainController
  self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have given my tab bar controller the name of myMainView but again i am being presented with

> Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1abc8c828) to 'apertureswift.mainController' (0x1000210a0).
>   2016-10-09 11:56:17.549751 apertureswift[544:55199] Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1abc8c828) to 'apertureswift.mainController' (0x1000210a0).

Comment: Can you present some more information?

Comment: is `mainController` a class or an object? Class names should be written with a leading uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you send to UITabbarController you should change mainConrtoller to UITabbarController and identifier . you must set identifier for UITabController

```
 let viewController:UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabcontroller") as! UITabbarController
  self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```